# 404 error: no user matches the given query?

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

I am busy with my group profile app and whenever i click on the create_group link i get this error instead of the create_group page. I think the problem may be in my URLS.PY file, has anybody ran into this problem. I am at work so will post some code in a few hours.

UPDATE:

The issue was in my URLS.py project file, i guess it wasn't syncing well with my urls.py app file. Such a small issue but it was really frustrating. Thats the life of a newbe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem. URL localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/add/ created 404. Solution was obvious after I first found it.

My accounts app had missing ^ in accounts/url.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'user/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'accounts.views.profile')
)
```

So I fixed it:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'accounts.views.profile')
)
```

The original matched with .../user/add/ before admin urls.py and caused the 404.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question, and without your code it's almost impossible to answer you correctly.  However, I'll take a stab at it.  It seems to me that you may be using the get_object_or_404 method in your view?  Or is this an admin view?  Either way, the answer is the same: You have a group profile and a reference to a user from that group that doesn't exist.  It seems like you may just have data inconsistencies in your DB.  I may be way off, it's hard to tell with so little information.  If you give me more information to work off, I'll amend my answer to give you a more complete response.

One thing I can tell you for sure is that is NOT a missing URL error message.  That error message is sending a 404 back because it can't retrieve an object from the DB.  This would occur after the URL pattern was matched.  However, I guess it's also possible that it's a user session issue, where you were logged in with a user that no longer exists, but that's just conjecture.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, i have uploaded my model.py snippet for group and my view snippet for group_create.